# Database system in website builder such as Wix or Squarespace

Tags: laravel, web, dynamic-programming, builder, velo

Are you familiar with website builder?
There are bunch of website builder companies such as `wix, squarespace, duda, odoo,shopify, weebly`...
Here, when we create account first, they assign subdomain of their website.
For instance, `companyname.shopifyapp.com, xxx.squarespace.com`

I think there are over 1 million customers for some websites.

Can anyone tell about database system of those websites?

If new customer signup and get his website, then will they save all his data in one big db including website template, setting and so on ?
I think if then, we can identify all data by subdomain or user id in one db.

Or they will generate code and database dynamically for each user?

Thanks.

Comment: Opinion based. But you can see one of [the concepts applied by Hyn](https://tenancy.dev/docs/hyn/5.4/concepts).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will take a look that link.